# How to extend ERB templating

Tags: ruby, erb

I would like to extend ERB so every output tag - <%= %> - content is pre-processed before the result is rendered.

For example,

```
<%= 'test' %>
```

should now render

```
!test!
```

instead of

```
test
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? (untested)

```
require 'erb'
template = File.read(template_file)
template.gsub!(/<%=(.*?)%>/, '!\1!')
erb = ERB.new(template)
result = erb.result
```

Comment: Nice, I think I could do template.gsub!(/<%=.*?=>/, 'preprocess(\1)') and add preprocess(content) method to the bindind. I'll try this now.

Comment: I guess you meant template.gsub!(/<%=(.*)%>/, '<%=!\1!%>'). The problem is that two method calls in the same line <%=function%><%=function%> is replaced by <%=!function %><%=function!%> because regex is greedy.

Comment: I guess I could exclude characters <>% from the regex - /<%=([^<>%]*)%>/ -, but I would have to allow them only when inside quotes.

Comment: Yeah, the parentheses are needed. However, you dropped the question mark, which was as necessary (excluding `<>%` is a hack). I'll revise in the answer... (The question mark makes the star non-greedy, so that it matches a minimal segment instead of the maximal, which happens with greedy star, i.e. without the question mark.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now ! I thought the question mark meant only once-or-nothing (optional), is this syntax common regex ?

Comment: Should you replace the last '=' of the regex by '%' ? /<%=(.*?)%>/

Comment: Yeah. As I said, I just wrote it in a hurry, didn't test worth a damn. The question mark has two meanings: one if it follows a token (0-or-1), and another if it follows a repetition operator (non-greedy, also called lazy). It can even follow itself: `x??` means "you can match an `x` if you really have to, but I'd rather you wouldn't".

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do that. Perhaps you can define:

```
class String; def bang; "!#{self}!" end end
```

and do

```
<%= "test".bang %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this approach is that I intend to generate 2 different outputs from the same template. One should be HTML and the other is a ESC/POS formatted text file to be printed in a epson fiscal printer